# Can I configure Visual Studio Code's Outline view to show what is public/private?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I configure Visual Studio Code to show in the Outline panel what the members and methods are in the sense of Public and Private? If so, how?

IntelliJ would show a green or a red marker to indicate which were private and which are publicly accessible methods and properties.

Comment: I've still not found a way to implement a view that shows what is public or private in the OUTLINE view in the Left column display. This does not seem to be a feature of VSCode.

Comment: I've wrote a comment including my research through VSCode issues. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50186#issuecomment-1232653589
So far I have contradictory informations. Also, at the documentation of VSCode there's no bookmark about outline icons so far https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme

Comment: Free comes at the cost of TIME and a lot of it wasted.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you theoretically could achieve this in an extension by using the detail property of [`DocumentSymbol`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbol), which I think is what shows to the right of the name in the Outline View, but the extension providing language support would need to actually do that (so I guess the more practical answer for someone who doesn't want to go writing a language support extension or forking one would be to go check for an existing feature-request issue ticket or create one in the specific extension's issue tracker). If you want something that looks nicer than that / looks different / uses an icon instead of text / is differently positioned, then you'd need to file an issue ticket against VS Code itself. There's also a `kind` property, but its type, [`SymbolKind`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SymbolKind) doesn't have any sort of modifier mechanism.

Note that the [`FileDecoration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileDecoration) part of the extension API has a `badge` property, which I think can affect the Explorer View. An extension could also just contribute its own type of subview to the Explorer View which does whatever it wants.